# Scringo - Managing our own users

Tags: android, chat, scringo

I am trying to implement a Group Chat within our application. I have get started with Scringo. I am able to use the exisiting example projects to open the default chat interface and Signup inside the Scringo App. I do not want users to sign up inside the Chat.

I have a separate database of users who will login. How do I integrate MyUser info with the ScringoUser classes ? 
The most relevant details I can get from my one hour of google search/Scringo docs search is this..

http://www.scringo.com/docs/api/android/com/scringo/ScringoGetUserListener.html

According to the below link for Scringo Docs, it seems they are allowing it. But I find no information on the APIs which are related to registering our users into the Scringo User database. 
http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/setup-a-chat-client/

Can someone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It is possible to integrate Scringo chat interface as well as to **manage our own users**.
Allow users to SignUp from your application and onSuccess programatically signup the user to Scringo using thier API.
On successfull registration of user at scringo, retrieve SCringo User ID and store it in your DB.
Thats it.
Now Play with scringo ID.

Link to follow:
[SCRINGO API DOC](http://www.scringo.com/docs/)